# How to apply a Gradle plugin

Tags: javascript, gradle

I am new to gradle. We use gradle for our project but this is the first time I am having to make gradle related changes.

I am trying to use the gradle js plugin for minifying. [Here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.eriwen.gradle.js) is a link to the doc.

I added the classpath for plugin to the existing buildScript dependencies object and then do ***gradlew clean build*** from the command line and it builds sucessfully.

After adding `apply plugin: 'com.eriwen.gradle.js'` and rebuilding, I get the following error:

> Plugin with id 'com.eriwen.gradle.js' not found.

Here is the existing buildScript to which I have added classpath for plugin

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins-release"
        }

    }
    dependencies {      
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.0'
        classpath 'com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:1.11.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.eriwen.gradle.js"
```

What am I missing here?

Gradle v. is 1.9 and plugin v. is 1.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mentioned plugin *apply id* for version *1.11.0* is **js**, so it will be:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {      
        classpath 'com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:1.11.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'js'
```

BTW: this plugin is available to download via `mavenCentral()`.

To verify it download [this](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin/1.11.0/gradle-js-plugin-1.11.0.jar) artifact, extract it and display the content of:

```
cat META-INF/gradle-plugins/js.properties
```

file, which is:

```
implementation-class=com.eriwen.gradle.js.JsPlugin
```

The file name (*js*) of this *js.properties* file is the ID you need to apply.

Comment: So I replaced my buildScript with yours and set apply plugin to 'js' and now I am getting the following error:"Could not create an instance of type com.eriwen.gradle.js.JavaScriptExtension_Decorated". I downloaded the artifact and placed the 'com' folder amongst a bunch of other folders in my project prefixed with 'com'. Could it be that I placed it in the wrong location? if so, where should it go? thanks.

Comment: @stackato, there's no need to download, extract and copy the plugin to your project - it all happens automatically and it's handled by gradle. I added this steps in my answer, just for clarification - to show you how it works. Please, just change the build script and it should work fine.

Comment: ok, got it. Its still not working but I believe it may be because of a version mismatch between gradle 1.9 and the plugin. Trying to set up a different version of gradle now.

Comment: Sure. Please let me know if you've worked it out finally.

Comment: I was able to download the js plugin after switching to gradle v 1.12. Thanks for all your help.